# Colour arrows graphdrawing

Tags: color, nodes, graphs, tikz-graphdrawing, edge

I am using **graphdrawing** tikz to create a small tree. In the MWE below, I would like to have a blue arrow pointing to B1 and an orange arrow pointing to B2. How could I do this?

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\newcommand{\eg}{\textit{e.g., }}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, every node/.style={minimum size=0.75cm}]
\graph [tree layout, grow=down, fresh nodes, level distance=0.5in, sibling distance=0.5in]
    {
        Model -> {
            "A1" ->[very thick, blue] {B1 -> {C, D}, B2},
            A2 -> {C}
        } 
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, the command ```\newcommand{\eg}{\textit{e.g., }}``` is useless here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `B2[>orange]` to (specially) specify the incoming edge (the arrow) of `B2` in orange. See `pgfmanual` 3.1.6a, sec. 19.6.4 *Special Syntax for Options For Incoming and Outgoing Edges*.

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\newcommand{\eg}{\textit{e.g., }}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, every node/.style={minimum size=0.75cm}]
\graph [tree layout, grow=down, fresh nodes, level distance=0.5in, sibling distance=0.5in]
    {
        Model -> {
            "A1" ->[very thick, blue] {B1 -> {C, D}, B2[>orange]},
            A2 -> {C}
        } 
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, I could not find it in the ```pfgmanual``` (I was looking at chapter 28 - Using Graph Drawing in TikZ). I accepted your answer

Comment: @mistral I found the usage in the second example in sec. 19.1 with only a bit effort, but it do takes me more time to find the specific section which introduces that syntax. :)